# How to validate multiple edittext fields with a pop-up message or alert dialog box?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, validation, null

I'd like to know how to validate my 4 edittext fields if one or more of these fields are left empty after tapping the button to process the inputs. I have searched many solutions like using toast but  It think it's not appropriate for multiple edittext fields and using textwatchers. I'd like the app to show a pop-up message or alert dialog box saying "Please fill up the necessary fields."

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use setError. eg/- edittext.setError("");

Comment: Is that appropriate for validating multiple fields? If one or more fields are left empty by the user

Answer (score 2):

You can use below common function for checking the Null values of the edittext:

> ```
>  public static boolean m_isError;
>    public static void checkEntryForEmptyValue(EditText p_editText, String p_nullMsg)
> {
>     if (p_editText != null || p_nullMsg != null)
>     {
>         // use trim() while checking for blank values
>         if ((p_editText.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")) || (p_editText.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0))
>         {
>             m_isError = true;
>             p_editText.setError(p_nullMsg);
>             p_editText.requestFocus();
>         }
>     }
> }
> }
> ```

Use the above function as below inside your button click listener:

> ```
> CommonUtil.m_isError = false;
>    CommonUtil.checkEntryForEmptyValue(edittext,getResources().
>            getString(R.string.MessageEmpty));
>     if (!CustomValidator.m_isError) 
>     {
>       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>     }
>    else
>    {
>    //Your dialog with the error messages.
>    }
> ```

Comment: I'm getting errors regarding public static void checkEntryForEmptyValue(EditText p_editText, String p_nullMsg), it says illegal modifier for parameter String and final is only permitted and also checkEntryForEmptyValue cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: Is this applicable to multiple fields?

Comment: Can you show me how are you using it ? And yes it is applicable to multiple fields .

Answer (score 1):

u can use some tooltips for validation like qtip or poshytip

http://vadikom.com/demos/poshytip/

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/

Write a validation function to check all text fields and append the tooltip object with the corresponding fields which fails the validation.

Comment: It's a little too advanced for me. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kabichill/VXKv2/

check this fiddle dude. Hope its easy for u

Answer (score 1):

Use this validate function when you click on button and you can check the alert message after method is executed

```
boolean flag_1= true,flag_2=true,flag_3=true;
String alertmsg;
```

.

```
private boolean validate()
{
    EditText et1    = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
    EditText et2    = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2);
    EditText et3    = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et3);


    if(et1.getText().toString().isEmpty())
    {
        alertmsg+=  "Please fill 1st\n";
        flag_1  =   false;
    }
    if(et2.getText().toString().isEmpty())
    {
        alertmsg+=  "Please fill 2nd\n";
        flag_2  =   false;
    }
    if(et3.getText().toString().isEmpty())
    {
        alertmsg+=  "Please fill 3rd";
        flag_3  =   false;  
    }

    return flag_1||flag_2||flag_3;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

**EDIT:**

Call this `onClick` of your process-input button:

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mRlayout1);
boolean success = formIsValid(rl);
if(success == false){
  // alert dialog box
}
else{
  // process ahead
}
```

Declare this function:

**EDIT:**

```
public boolean formIsValid(RelativeLayout layout) {
    for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = layout.getChildAt(i);
        Class<? extends View> c = v.getClass();
        if (c == EditText.class) {
            EditText et = (EditText) v;
            if(et.getText().toString().equals(""))
                return false;
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+et.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                
        } 
    }
    return true;
}
```

By this you can validate **N number of input controls** with **single call**.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm getting a warning on the success variable in boolean success = formIsValid(rl);

Comment: And also in Class, it says that Class is a raw type.

Comment: @AprilMosca see my edited solution for that. THat will work exactly same as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The Simplest soulution is that check that if the fields are empty then show dialog here is simple code snippet

```
  private void checkEntries()
{

    if(!(email.getText().toString().equals("")))    
    {
        if(!(pass.getText().toString().equals("")))
        {
            if(UIHelper.getInstance().emailAddressValidation(email.getText().toString()))
            {
                if(pass.getText().length()>=5)
                {
                    sendLoginRequest(email.getText().toString(),pass.getText().toString(),Constants.PHONE_ID);
                }
                else
                {
                    dialogBoxInUIthread("String","Password length should be greater than 5 ",LoginController.this,true);
                }
            }
            else
            {

                dialogBoxInUIthread("String","Invalid Email Id",LoginController.this,true);

            }   
        }
        else
        {
            dialogBoxInUIthread("String","Please enter password",LoginController.this,true);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dialogBoxInUIthread("String","Please enter email",LoginController.this,true);
    }

}



private void dialogBoxInUIthread(final String title,final String msg, Context context,final boolean completed) {
         /* runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {*/
            AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginController.this);
            alertbox.setTitle(title);
            alertbox.setMessage(msg);
            alertbox.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                   if(completed){
                   }else{ }
               }
              });alertbox.show();
          /* }
          });*/
    }
```