# How to set focus EditText After validation active in Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, validation, touch

If a user enters an invalid email or leaves it empty, I want to show a Toast message and set the focus to the email text field.

Comment: try.. **editText.requestFocus();**

Comment: check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393442/how-to-validate-multiple-edittext-fields-with-a-pop-up-message-or-alert-dialog-b?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
EditText etEmailID = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.etEmailID);
String emailID= etEmailID.getText().toString();
Context mContext = MainActivity.this; // Your_Context

if(emailID.isEmpty() || !android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(emailID.matches())
  {
     Toast.makeText(mContext, "Please enter valid recipient address", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     etEmailID.requestFocus(emailID.length());
  }
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: above code will produce an **ERROR** - parenthesis are placed incorrectly when validating the email within the `if-statement`. Instead it must be: `if (emailID.isEmpty() || !android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(emailID).matches()) {...}`

Comment: tried to edit @Andrain's answer accordingly but unfortunately my edit suggestion was rejected.

Answer (score 0):

To get focus and show the keyboard you would write something like this:

```
 if(myEditText.requestFocus()) {
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "your message to displayed on the screen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this for email validation..

```
EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    if(email.getText().toString().equals("")){
        email.requestFocus();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "please enter email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    }
    if(!eMailValidation(email.getText().toString())){
        email.requestFocus();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "please enter valid email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    }
```

eMailValidation(String email) is.

```
public static boolean eMailValidation(String email) {
    emailPattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\.\\_\\%\\-\\+]{1,256}"
            + "\\@" + "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,64}" + "(" + "\\."
            + "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,25}" + ")+");
    emailMatcher = emailPattern.matcher(email);
    return emailMatcher.matches();
}
```